# Query Ignoring Date with search

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Good morning everyone,

Im having an issue that I have not seen before where the date parameter im using is totally ignored and the query is giving me ambigious results.

the code im using is

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE VARCHAR='03/07/2018'

Select 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, CloseDateTime, 103 ) AS INSPECTION_DATE,
    CallProperties.ID,
    (CallProperties.UserRef) AS ENGINEER,
    (CallProperties.CallRef) as ReferenceNo,
    (CallProperties.CallTypeName) as JobType,
    (SELECT2) AS VEN_POSTCODE, 

    (ADVANCED_oil.PARENTid) AS PARENTID, 

    ADVANCED_oil.Panel_CustDetails_C_EAddress,
    (ADVANCED_oil.Adv_OilTestComplete) as OilTestTaken


    from CallProperties left JOIN ADVANCED_oil ON  (ADVANCED_oil.ParentID=CallProperties.ID) where Adv_OilTestComplete='Low oil' 
   OR Adv_OilTestComplete='Tube restriction'
   OR Adv_OilTestComplete='No dip stick' 
   OR Adv_OilTestComplete='Vendor refused' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR,  CloseDateTime,  103 )=@STARTDATE
```

its supposed to give me one result back but keeps giving me 7 rows, some of which do not have anything  to do with the paramenter values....please help!!

Thankyou in advance

Comment: Tag the question with the database you are using (which I presume is SQL Server).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem starts with the first line:

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE VARCHAR = '03/07/2018'
```

There are two major things wrong and one important but not major:

- Dates should be *DATES*, not strings.
- You have declared a string with one character.
- You should *always* use proper ISO standard date formats

Change this to:

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATE = '2018-07-03';
```

Then do the comparison as a date:

```
CONVERT(DATE, CloseDateTime) = @STARTDATE
```

As far as I know, `CONVERT()` and `CAST()` to `DATE` are the only functions that still allow an index to be used.

EDIT:

Your `where` clause is also malformed.  You probably intend:

```
where Adv_OilTestComplete IN ('Low oil', 'Tube restriction', 'No dip stick', 'Vendor refused') AND
      CONVERT(DATE, CloseDateTime) = @STARTDATE
```

Comment: Thankyou for the heads up Gordan.

Comment: ive changes the code as advised but it is still returning 6 rows.

Answer (score 0):

the main issue in you code in filter part

```
where Adv_OilTestComplete='Low oil' 
OR Adv_OilTestComplete='Tube restriction'
OR Adv_OilTestComplete='No dip stick' 
OR Adv_OilTestComplete='Vendor refused' AND CONVERT(DATE, CloseDateTime) = @STARTDATE
```

it has to be like this

```
   where (Adv_OilTestComplete='Low oil' 
    OR Adv_OilTestComplete='Tube restriction'
    OR Adv_OilTestComplete='No dip stick' 
    OR Adv_OilTestComplete='Vendor refused') AND CONVERT(DATE, CloseDateTime) = @STARTDATE
```

because And has higher priority than or you can check this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: do you sill have the same issue? @LeonM